# Manage multiple recycler view inside Single nested scrollview

Tags: android

I have one nested scrollview, within this one is autoscroll view pager and 4 recycler views one below the other. When the nested scroll view scrolls up and the last recycler view appears on the top a filter button should get visible to the header section. How can I manage visibility of button when Last recycler view comes at the top. 2 snaps are here for example:
first: [image]

second is the view when the last recycler view comes on Top and filter button get visible on the header.[image]

Please Help.

Comment: is the filter button is menu item or the whole toolbar is a custom view?

Comment: its a custom view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for NestedScrollView to check that if your salon list is visible and if it is then you can show the filter icon else make its visibility gone.

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        nestedScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if (salonRecyclerView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {

            // Here make visible the filter icon since you salon list is visible
            if (!filterIcon.isVisible()) {
                filterIcon.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {

            // Here make visible GONE of filter icon since you salon list is not visible
            if (filterIcon.isVisible()) {
                filterIcon.setVisible(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to scroll till end. When salon list appears i want to visible filter icon also if we scroll down and the salon list is completely scrolled down, icon must get hide.

Comment: See my answer I have made some changes as you mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Amazing I was in trouble from last 2 days and your solution worked like charm... Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you :)